# Certificate request with CRMF format

Tags: openssl, ca

Normally I use OpenSSL to create certificate requests (PKCS#10).

But now I have to use a CA that requires CRMF format (RFC 4111).

Any idea what tool I can use to create this??

Comment: Meanwile I created some tool for doing that.
Java and BouncyCastle has the ability.